# Determine if app uses prototype js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

Im taking over an app that was started by someone else. I want to use jquery, but from what i read, the only way to use it replaces Prototype. This shouldnt be a problem, but im not sure if the project uses any protoype. Is there a plugin i can run or something that searches the project and checks compatibility without prototype?

Comment: What does `console.log(Prototype.Version);` print ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any.  The only way I can think of doing it would be to make the change and hunt for errors then translate them to JQuery.  Most are not hard.  They are usually just slight differences like `addClass` instead of `addClassName`

Comment: Thats what it looks like im going to end up doing

Answer (score 0):

You can use both prototype and jquery, using [jquery's NoConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode. You can also look at the [jquery-rails](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails) plugin that removes prototype and reimplements the helpers using jquery.